# MySQL Save/Load Issue

Tags: java, mysql, database

Ok So I have a program where I add new Players to a database, and where I load them users into a list. The problem is when I delete a user, then go to add a new user the new player gets added in to where the old user was. Basically because that spot is free now and I use:

```
rs.moveToInsertRow();
```

is there a way that when adding a new player it 'Always' adds to the end of the the database. Like when you delete a row from table to make the database compress so it has no gaps?

here is the code:

public static void Save()
{
     try
    {

```
String Name = "#####";
     String Pass= "#####";
    String Host = "######";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(String.format(
    "jdbc:mysql://%s:%s/%s", Host, "####", "####"),
    Name, Pass);
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement (ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);



    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Accounts";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


     rs.moveToInsertRow( );

        String userName= TestForm.UsernameTextField.getText(); //make this equal to whats in textfield
        String password= TestForm.PasswordTextField.getText(); //make this equal to whats in textfield

        String insertQuery="insert into Accounts (`Username`,`Password`) values ('"+userName+"','"+password+"');";
        stmt.executeUpdate(insertQuery);

     stmt.close();
     rs.close();
}

catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("ERROR");
    e.printStackTrace();
}


}
```

Comment: Do you have an autoincrement primary key on your Accounts table?

Comment: the primary key is the username field

Comment: So what connotes "order" to you? Just doing a "SELECT *" with no ORDER BY clause does not guarantee any specific order for the result set.  If you add an autoincrement field, your newly inserted row will automatically have a different, higher number value than the one that was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem add one column 'id' . That column should be `auto increment`. Also make your `Username` unique.